# Managed Metadata in a library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, managed-metadata

I am using SharePoint Server 2013. I am filtering the documents in the SharePoint Library using the managed metadata an shown below.

[image]

I want to know is there is any way to display the columns as check boxes and not as drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

There is always building your own page with a javascript to build a 'unordered list' as check boxes.  If you look up 'Ol' samples of javascripts it may give you hints on it.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your idea. Could you explain more or give me a good link to understand? Thank you @MEV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173649/create-and-add-a-li-element-to-an-ordered-list-using-javascript-jquery